# How to get values from different input name via serialized form to insert into mysql?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I have this dynamic FORM, I have a jQuery function to insert more than one row in the form:

```
<form id="forma2" name="items">         
    <table id="prodItems" class="table table-hover table-bordered" style="width:100%">

        <!-- ENCABEZADOS -->
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <!-- <th style="width:8%">Partida</th> -->
                <th style="width:8%" >Cantidad</th>
                <th style="width:15%">Modelo</th>
                <th style="width:15%">S/N</th>
                <th style="width:70%">Descripcion</th>
                <th style="width:3%">Check</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <!-- FIN ENCABEZADOS -->
        <!-- INGRESO DE DATOS DE PRODUCTOS -->
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <!-- <td>1</td> -->
                <td>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input class="form-control cantClass" name="n_cantidad[]" maxlength="5" placeholder="#"/>
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input class="form-control autocompletModelo" id="modelo1" name="n_modelo[]" maxlength="20" placeholder="XXX-XXXXX" type="text"/>
                    </div>
                </td>   
                <td>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input class="form-control serieClass" name="n_serie[]"  maxlength="20" placeholder="12345ABC"/>
                    </div>
                </td>   
                <td>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <textarea readonly class="form-control descrClass" id ="descripcion1" rows="2" name="n_descripcion[]"  maxlength="300" placeholder="Descripcion del Material"/></textarea>
                    </div>
                </td>   
                <td>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type='checkbox' class='check'/>
                    </div>
                </td>                   
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    <!-- FIN  INGRESO DE DATOS DE PRODUCTOS -->
    </table>
```

Im using jQuery to serialize the form (more than one row at the same time) :

```
$("#enviarDatos").click(function(){

  stringProductos = $("#forma2").serializeArray();
  var v_empresa = $("#empresa").val();
  var v_contacto = $("#contacto").val();
  var v_entrega = $("#entrega").val();
  var v_id = $("#identificador").val();
  var v_fecha = $("#fecha").val(); 

  var dataString = 'empresa='+ v_empresa + '&contacto='+ v_contacto + '&entrega='+ v_entrega +'&identificador='+ v_id + '&fecha=' + v_fecha + '&' + stringProductos ;

    {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "registro-remision.php",
            data: dataString,
            cache: false,
            success: function() {
                $('.confirmacion').text(dataString).addClass('confirmacion_ok'); 
                alert(dataString); 
            },
            error: function() {
                $('.confirmacion').text('Hubo un error! Intenta de nuevo ').addClass('confirmacion_error');
            }
        });
    } 
return false;
});
```

I need to save the form (all rows) in MySQL via PHP, but  I don't know how to get the information from the serialize() form to do this job .

Could you help me ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use **[`serialize()`](https://api.jquery.com/serialize/)** not **[`serializeArray()`](https://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/)**

```
var stringProductos = $("#forma2").serialize();
```

Comment: You  can access the value using `$_POST` in php

Comment: I'm using post  for example :
$v_modelo = ($_POST['n_modelo']); but only I can access and insert into MySQL v_modelo[0] . If I try to get v_modelo[1] Is not working .

Comment: @JulioMartinez : there is only one input field with that name

Answer (score 0):

```
var stringProductos = $("#forma2").serialize();
$.ajax({
url:"write Your url where you Get Data",
type:"POST",
Data:stringProductos,
success:function(data)
        {
           console.log(data);
        }
});
```

**In Your PHP Page**

```
print_r($_POST);
```